# ThreadPoolExecutor with unbounded queue not creating new threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

My `ThreadPoolExecutor` is failing to create new threads.  In fact I wrote a somewhat hacky `LinkedBlockingQueue` that will accept any task (i.e. it is unbounded) but call an additional handler - which in my application spews warning trace that the pool is behind - which gives me very explicit information that the TPE is refusing to create new threads even though the queue has thousands of entries in it.  My constructor is as follows:

```
private final ExecutorService s3UploadPool = 
new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 40, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, unboundedLoggingQueue);
```

Why is it not creating new threads?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528304/how-to-get-the-threadpoolexecutor-to-increase-threads-to-max-before-queueing/19528305#19528305

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This gotcha is covered in [this blog post](https://github.com/kimchy/kimchy.github.com/blob/master/_posts/2008-11-23-juc-executorservice-gotcha.textile):

> This construction of thread pool will simply not work as expected. This is due to the logic within the ThreadPoolExecutor where new threads are added if there is a **failure** to offer a task to the queue. In our case, we use an unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue, where we can always offer a task to the queue. It effectively means that we will never grow above the core pool size and up to the maximum pool size.

If you also need to decouple the minimum from maximum pool sizes, you will have to do some extended coding.  I am not aware of a solution that exists in the Java libraries or Apache Commons.  The solution is to create a coupled `BlockingQueue` that is aware of the TPE, and will go out of its way to reject a task if it knows the TPE has no threads available, then manually requeue.  It is covered in more detail in linked post.  Ultimately your construction will look like:

```
public static ExecutorService newScalingThreadPool(int min, int max, long keepAliveTime) {
   ScalingQueue queue = new ScalingQueue();
   ThreadPoolExecutor executor =
      new ScalingThreadPoolExecutor(min, max, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
   executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ForceQueuePolicy());
   queue.setThreadPoolExecutor(executor);
   return executor;
}
```

However more simply set `corePoolSize` to `maxPoolSize` and don't worry about this nonsense.

Comment: note, you can still get a limited scaling effect by allowing core threads to timeout (you can scale from 0 to max threads).

Comment: According to the javadocs: By setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create a fixed-size thread pool. So if you follow your last sentence you'd be better off just using a Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize).

Comment: @darrickc looks like your edit was already rejected but it would be appropriate to include it in comment.  I don't think it's valid because in my use cases I don't want threads to time out.

Comment: what does it mean that the task will be rejected? what are the consequences? Also, how come when I change the code of AsyncTask (of Android) to use a simple LinkedBlockingQueue , it works fine and does create new threads according to the parameters i've set for ThreadPoolExecutor CTOR ?

Answer (score 6):

There is a workaround to this problem. Consider the following implementation:

```
int corePoolSize = 40;
int maximumPoolSize = 40;
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, 
    60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
threadPoolExecutor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

By setting the [allowCoreThreadTimeOut()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut%28boolean%29) to `true`, the threads in the pool are allowed to terminate after the specified timeout (60 seconds in this example). With this solution, it is the `corePoolSize` constructor argument that determines the maximum pool size in practice, because the thread pool will grow up to the `corePoolSize`, and then start adding jobs to the queue. It is likely that the pool may never grow bigger than that, because the pool will not spawn new threads until the queue is full (which, given that the `LinkedBlockingQueue` has an `Integer.MAX_VALUE` capacity may never happen). Consequently, there is little point in setting `maximumPoolSize` to a larger value than `corePoolSize`.

Consideration: The thread pool have 0 idle threads after the timeout has expired, which means that there will be some latency before the threads are created (normally, you would always have `corePoolSize` threads available).

More details can be found in the JavaDoc of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @djechlin, this is part of the (surprising to many) defined behavior of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  I believe I've found a somewhat elegant solution around this behavior that I show in my answer here:

> [How to get the ThreadPoolExecutor to increase threads to max before queueing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528304/how-to-get-the-threadpoolexecutor-to-increase-threads-to-max-before-queueing/19528305#19528305)

Basically you extend `LinkedBlockingQueue` to have it always return false for `queue.offer(...)` which will add an additional threads to the pool, if necessary. If the pool is already at max threads and they all are busy, the `RejectedExecutionHandler` will be called. It is the handler which then does the `put(...)` into the queue.

See my code there.