# Spring batch corePoolSize VS throttle-limit

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I'd like to know the difference between **corePoolSize** and **throttle-limit** as Spring Batch attributes defining multi threading configuration.

I've got the difference between corePoolSize and maxPoolSize thanks to this post ["What is the difference between corePoolSize and maxPoolSize in the Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1879487/1529015)

But my issue concerns **corePoolSize** vs **throttle-limit**... I found that it's preferable to define CorePoolSize = Throttle-limit, but I'm wondering... if I define for example :
CorePoolSize = 100 and Throttle-limit = 200... What happens ? Is a 200 sized thread pool that will be created or 100 ?

Thank you for any clarification...

Comment: No body has an answer ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The core pool size says a thread pool executor will start with `N` number of threads. A throttle-limit `T` says that, regardless of the number of threads available in the thread pool, only use `T` of those threads for a tasklet.

So you can have a thread pool with a core pool size of 8 and two tasklets with throttle limit of 4 in that case you will be utilizing your thread pool. But if you only have one tasklet with a throttle limit of 4 you will be utilizing one half of the thread pool.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification John, but what if the throttle-limit exceeds the corePoolSize ?  for example Throttle-limit = 200 and CorePoolSize = 100 ? will the JVM crash ?

Comment: I don't know the implementation, but my best guess is that there a semaphore to throttle and excess submissions to the thread pool will simply cause those submissions to be queued up and executed at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**throttle-limit** is explained in the spring batch javadocs in [TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/repeat/support/TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.html#setThrottleLimit-int-).

This is another property on top of all the possible ways to configure a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and probably simplifies the task of using a thread pool. It's certainly useful if you have [parallel steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#scalabilityParallelSteps) competing for threads.

To answer your question, new threads will be created for your tasks if your throttle-limit is greater than `corePoolSize` only if `maximumPoolSize` is greater than `corePoolSize` and the blocking queue in your ThreadPoolExecutor is full. Otherwise they will e.g. queue up in your ThreadPoolExecutor or possibly be rejected with an exception (see the default handler [AbortPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy.html)).

What happens when spring batch tries to submit more tasks to the executor than it is willing to accept depends on your executor. See **Rejected tasks** in the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) javadocs.

It's all a bit confusing at first, but makes perfect sense in the end.

Note that `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_LIMIT` is 4 (in my spring version).

See for example this [gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485840/threadpoolexecutor-with-unbounded-queue-not-creating-new-threads) when your ThreadPoolExecutor is unexpectedly not creating any more than *corePoolSize* Threads.